# UIImagePickerController with UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera crash

Tags: ios

I have the following code:

```
if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Camera is not available." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    return;
}

UIImagePickerController * cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
[cameraUI setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
[cameraUI setMediaTypes:@[(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie]];
[cameraUI setAllowsEditing:NO];
[cameraUI setDelegate:self];

[navigationController presentViewController:cameraUI animated:YES completion:^{

    NSLog(@"completed present camera controller");

}];
```

and I get this crash:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
```

---

It happens on iOS7, iOS8, iPad & iPhone.
If I comment the "present" method, it doesn't crash, but after commenting each line one by one, I found that this is the only one that crashes my app (without it the "present" works and it takes me to library):

```
[cameraUI setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
```

I'm really out of ideas here. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: are you running this in simulator?  the simulator doesn't have a camera, so it has a problem with setting the source type to camera.

Comment: no, the devices used are iPad mini, iPad Air2, iPhone 5c, and iPhone 5s

Comment: I ran into the same issue with presenting.  I added the view as a subview and animated it.

Comment: I tried `[navigationController.view addSubview:cameraUI.view];` and I get the same crash... this is getting really frustrating

Comment: Instead of navigationController.view, what about self.view?  There seems to be an issue with your nav controller.

Comment: I even tried putting it in the delegate's window and still the same error occurs.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that you never set the frame of the image picker controller. Maybe that's an issue?

Comment: @PaulDobrea have you tried: [self presentViewController:cameraUI animated:YES completion:Nil];

Comment: yes, I tried with nil completion block, same issue.

Comment: @PaulDobrea no I'm refer to use "self" and not "navigationController"

Comment: yes, I've tried that too, the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, maybe someone will encounter the same problem sometime... I needed a property set on all the buttons inside my app, so I created a `UIButton` category in which I had overridden `-initWithFrame:`, and this caused the crash. Apparently something needed to happen there for the camera UI that wasn't happening anymore.

Comment: Got the same problem. Did yo find a way to make that work?